# limit point and isolated point example.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to understand limit point and isolated point conceptually with example. Do you think my approach is correct.

**Example for limit point:**

Let's consider an example in the real number line, which is a one-dimensional version of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's consider the set $E = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. This set includes elements like 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, and so on. You can imagine this set as points on the number line that get closer and closer to 0 as n increases.

The point $x = 0$ is a limit point (or accumulation point or cluster point) of the set $E$. Here's why:

For every $r > 0$, no matter how small, we can find a point in $E$ within $r$ of $0$. For example, if we choose $r = 0.001$, we can find an $n$ such that $1/n < 0.001$. Here, if $n > 1000$, then $1/n < 0.001$.

In other words, the "ball" $B_r(0)$ (which in this one-dimensional case is just the interval $(0-r, 0+r)$) contains points from $E$. And we can do this for any $r$ we choose, no matter how small. So there are points in $E$ that are arbitrarily close to $0$, which is the definition of a limit point. Therefore, $0$ is a limit point of $E$.

**Example for Isolated point:**

Let's say we have the set $E = \{1, 2, 3, 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 3\}$. This set includes elements like 1, 2, 3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, and so on.

Now, consider the point $x = 2$. This point is an isolated point of the set $E$. Here's why:

There exists an $r > 0$ (say, $r = 0.5$) such that the ball $B_r(2)$ contains only the point $x = 2$ from the set $E$. In other words, no other point in $E$ is within $r$ of 2.

Remember that in this one-dimensional case, a "ball" $B_r(x)$ is just the interval $(x - r, x + r)$. So $B_{0.5}(2) = (1.5, 2.5)$, and no other points from $E$ fall within this interval. Therefore, $2$ is an isolated point of $E$.

Furthermore, it's also clear that $2$ is not a limit point of $E$ because there is an open interval around $2$ that contains no points of $E$ other than $2$ itself. Thus, according to the second definition, $2$ is indeed an isolated point of $E$.

Comment: Isolated points (of a set) are points (in the set) that are not limit points (of the set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Limit Point of E: We want to show that $0$ is the only limit point of E.

   - Consider any $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to show that there exists an element $x \neq 0$ in E such that $|x - 0| < \varepsilon$.
   - Let $N$ be the smallest natural number greater than $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Since $\frac{1}{N} > \varepsilon$, we have $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$.
   - Hence, $\frac{1}{N}$ is an element of E, and it satisfies the condition $|\frac{1}{N} - 0| < \varepsilon$.
   - This implies that 0 is a limit point of E.
   - Now, let's show that no element other than 0 can be a limit point of E.
   - Consider any element $x \neq 0$ in E. There exists a natural number $n$ such that $x = \frac{1}{n}$.
   - Take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2n}$. It follows that for any $m > n$, we have $\frac{1}{m} < \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2n}$.
   - Therefore, there exists no element $y \neq x$ in E such that $|y - x| < \varepsilon$.
   - Thus, no element other than 0 can be a limit point of E.
2. Isolated Points of E: We want to show that for any finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n}$ is an isolated point of E in $\mathbb{R}$.

   - Consider any finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We need to show that there exists a neighborhood around $\frac{1}{n}$ that contains no other element of E.
   - Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2n}$. Consider the interval $(\frac{1}{n} - \varepsilon, \frac{1}{n} + \varepsilon)$.
   - Any element $x \neq \frac{1}{n}$ in E satisfies $x = \frac{1}{m}$ for some $m \neq n$.
   - Since $\frac{1}{m} \neq \frac{1}{n}$, we have $|\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}| \geq \frac{1}{n} > \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2n}$.
   - Hence, no element other than $\frac{1}{n}$ lies in the interval $(\frac{1}{n} - \varepsilon, \frac{1}{n} + \varepsilon)$.
   - Therefore, $\frac{1}{n}$ is an isolated point of E.

This completes the proof that 0 is the only limit point of the set $E = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and for any finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{n}$ is an isolated point of E in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Proof for point 2 is incorrect and falls apart around the 4th bullet point. Let $n=2$ so that the point considered is $1/2$ and set $x=1/3$. Then $\vert 1/3 - 1/2 \vert = 1/6$, which is **smaller** than $1/2$ (and indeed, even smaller than $1/2*2=1/4$).

Answer (score 4):

COMMENT.- I give you here an example of isolated point which something aditional: calculators as DESMOS and other don't put it when plotting the graphic:

The function
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x-3)$$ has the isolated point $(1,0)$; in general $f(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)$ has the isolated point $(a,0)$. But this point does not appear when plotting the curve with the usual calculators.

The curve seems to be an elliptic cubic but it is of genus zero (a rational cubic) whose singularity does not appear at simple first glance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it does not need to be so complicated. Indeed in your first example,

$$ \textbf{E} := \{\frac1n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{R} $$

We have 0 is the only limit point of the set, and for any finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac1n$ is an isolated point of E in R. Proof left as an exercise...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! can you give me example for R^2

Answer (score 0):

okay, then proof of your exercise can be:

The set $E=\{\frac{1}{n}:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ does indeed have $0$ as its only limit point, since for any radius $r>0$, no matter how small, we can find points in $E$ that are arbitrarily close to $0$. This is due to the property of $1/n$ getting arbitrarily close to $0$ as $n$ gets large.

Additionally, each point $\frac{1}{n}$ for finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is indeed an isolated point of $E$. For each such point, we can find an $r>0$ (for example $r=\frac{1}{2n}$ or $r=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$) such that the ball $B_r(\frac{1}{n})$ contains only the point $\frac{1}{n}$ from the set $E$. There are no other points from $E$ within this interval, therefore each $\frac{1}{n}$ is an isolated point of $E$.